# ¿Cómo personalizar los iconos de notificación de OneSignal Flutter en Android?

Tags: android, flutter, notificaciones, onesignal

Tengo el problema de que no puedo cambiarle el icono de la campanita a las notificaciones utilizando `onesignal_flutter: ^3.3.0` para Flutter android.

https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aunque sea una pregunta autorrespondida, procura agregar más detalles a tu pregunta para que sea útil a los demás miembros de la comunidad. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega lo siguiente a tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.onesignal.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_onesignal_default" />
```

Puedes usar [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html) para generar los iconos

Agregar “ic_stat_onesignal_default.png” a:

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/(24x24)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ (36x36)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/ (48x48)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ (72x72)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ (96x96)

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ (256x256) (Large Icon)

Fuente: https://medium.com/@jmangandid/iconos-personalizados-onesignal-flutter-android-934671693c85

Answer (score 0):

Usando **OneSignal Flutter SDK**, el icono de la notificación debe ser definido en el atributo `android:resource` de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` , el icono por default se encuentra dentro del directorio `mipmap/` :

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_stat_onesignal_default" />
```

pero puedes agregar ahí otro icono y cambiarlo dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, ejemplo :

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/my_notification:icon" />
```

Además de definir el icono en el directorio `/mipmap` , puedes hacer uso del directorio `/drawable` , ejemplo:

```
   <meta-data
                android:name="com.onesignal.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/my_notification:icon" />
```

---

Usando **Firebase** el procedimiento es similar mediante el atributo `android:resource` de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
   android:resource="@mipmap/my_notification:icon" />
```